# Position body background starting at container end

Tags: html, css

I have a container that is 980 pixels wide. I want a background of the main page (the body) to start from the right of the container and continue as far right as the browser window goes, or until the image ends (whichever is sooner).

It I position the background image like this:

```
body    {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 10pt;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(images/image.jpg) no-repeat 980px top;
}
```

Then the background image will start 980 pixels from the left hand edge of the browser window but that means it will only work on one particular screen resolution.

I tired positioning an element with the background but that went off the edge of the screen and when I tried to hide the overflow, but that meant you couldn't scroll the main page to see the content on the low resolution or high zoom.

Is there a way to take the centre and then add 490 pixels to it so it will start from the end of the container? I'd prefer to able to do it with (X)HTML and CSS wihout having to resort of JavaScript.

Comment: can you provide any link?

Comment: you can do this:  `background-position: calc(50% + 490px) top;` like here: http://jsfiddle.net/z5HqE/ but that does not make much sense...

Comment: Thanks Nico. I'll have look at it tomorrow and see if I can fix it. Thanks.

Comment: That worked perfectly Nico. It's a pity you posted it as a comment though since if you'd posted it as an answer I could have selected it a best answer.

Answer (score 1):

One of many ways to solve this would be to create a `div` which only task is to hold your background. You can then place this div where you want using `position: absolute;`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5yqLg/1/)

Comment: I did try that Natalie but I didn't want the scroll bar when the div went off the side of the page with a low resolution browser.

Comment: Hm, you shouldn't get s scrollbar because of the div since it's absolute positioned. The scrollbar might appear because the body still has a margin. Remove the margin from the body(se updated fiddle) and the scrollbar should disappear.

Comment: I think that problem I had was placing to division. I needed it be be at the edge of the container. The container will be in the center of the page so I needed this to be 490 pixels right of the center, what ever the resolution.